# iOS, How to get online status of contacts in PJSIP?

Tags: ios, pjsip

I am developing an iOS Application using PJSIP, Now I've implemented contacts list, I want my Application to show the Current Status of Contacts. 
And I want to modify users Current remote status, that will be shown to Remote Contacts.

I am beginner, any help will be appreciated. 
thanks.

Comment: Having the same problem...